# C# Delegate function always resolves true for half of Dataset

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, delegates, datetimeoffset

I am trying to write a method that partitions a DataTable based on a given condition (delegate). My problem is that the condition I'm using always partitions exactly half the DataTable. The condition seems to resolve true for half the DataRows even when NO DataRows should resolve to true.

The method looks like this:

```
private DataTable PartitionDataTable(DataTable data, Func<DataRow, bool> condition) {

DataTable removedRows = data.Clone();
for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++) {
  if(condition(data.Rows[i])){
    removedRows.ImportRow(data.Rows[i]);
    data.Rows.Remove(data.Rows[i]);
  }
}
  return removedRows;
}
```

I call this method using this condition:

```
DataTable removed = PartitionDataTable(data, (row => DateTimeOffset.Parse(row["timestamp"].ToString()) < baselineTimestamp);
```

If the highest/max timestamp in the data object (DataTable) is a few minutes earlier than the 'baselineTimestamp', determined using `data.Compute("max([timestamp])", String.Empty)`, then half the records are still partitioned and removed when none of them should be because all of them are < baselineTimestamp.

No idea what's going on. Please help me. The goal is to partition DataRows with timestamps earlier than a given (to the nearest milisecond).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing rows as you iterate over the dataset. So if `i=2`, then you remove row 2, and row 3 is now row 2. You then increment `i`, operating on the new row 3 (which was row 4) so you skip the original row 3 altogether.

One trick to resolve this is to iterate *backwards* since the rows that are shifted are ones that you've already processed:

```
for(int i = data.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(condition(data.Rows[i])){
    removedRows.ImportRow(data.Rows[i]);
    data.Rows.Remove(data.Rows[i]);
  }
}
  return removedRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you remove a row from `data` it's `Rows.Count` decreases.

Suppose `data` contains 10 rows at the start.

You increment `i` to 5 while you remove 5 rows from `data`.

On next iteration, `i` is 6, and `data.Rows.Count` is 5, the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing elements from an array, you have to move backward. If you do it forward, you'll skip half of the elements, and this is why you get half of them back:

```
DataTable removedRows = data.Clone();
for(int i = data.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  if(condition(data.Rows[i])){
    removedRows.ImportRow(data.Rows[i]);
    data.Rows.Remove(data.Rows[i]);
  }
}
  return removedRows;
}
```